# How can I make a Kubernetes multi-cluster Redis solution?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I deployed this week a Redis instance using Bitnami's Helm Chart into a GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) cluster. Although I've been successful on this part, the challenge now is to make a failover disaster recovery strategy that replicates the data to another Redis instance in another GKE cluster (but same GCP project). How can I do this? I tried Persistence Volume Claims but they are only visible inside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Enterprise does have a WAN (multi-geo) replication mode, however I've never used it and it looks like it dramatically limits which features of Redis you can use to things that are compatible with a CRDT model. Basically first you need to answer how you would do this by hand, and then investigate automating that. WAN failover is a very complex thing, and generally you wouldn't even want to do it since you wouldn't fail over at the Redis level. Instead you would fail over your entire DC (or whatever you want to call your failure zones). Distributed database modelling and management is very tricky, here be dragons.